# Unir muchas columnas

Tags: r, dataframe

Quiero unir en una sola columna varias columnas, por ejemplo

```
col1 <- c("Uno", NA, "tres", NA)
col2 <- c(NA, "dos", NA, NA)
col3 <- c(NA,NA,NA, "cuatro")

df <- data.frame(col1,col2, col3)

library(sqldf)

df2<-sqldf("select *, coalesce(col1,col2,col3 )  UNIDOS from df")
```

```
col1 col2   col3 UNIDOS
1  Uno <NA>   <NA>    Uno
2 <NA>  dos   <NA>    dos
3 tres <NA>   <NA>   tres
4 <NA> <NA> cuatro cuatro
```

Pero si en vez de 3 columnas son 300, como lo indico en esta parte

```
coalesce(col1,col2,col3......col300 )
```

para no escribir los 300?

He probado con

```
unir<-paste0("col", (seq(1,3)))

sqldf("select *, coalesce(unir)  UNIDOS from df")
```

Pero no sale

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Usando R base**

Podría ser de la siguiente manera

```
#Creamos df2 a partir de df
df2<-df

#Definimos las variables a unir
unir<-paste0("col",1:3)

# Usamos apply 
df2$UNIDOS<-apply(df2[,unir],MARGIN=1,function(x){
    # Removemos los NA de x
    x<-x[!is.na(x)]
    # Pegamos los valores
    paste(x,collapse="")
})

df2
  col1 col2   col3 UNIDOS
1  Uno <NA>   <NA>    Uno
2 <NA>  dos   <NA>    dos
3 tres <NA>   <NA>   tres
4 <NA> <NA> cuatro cuatro
```

Dentro de la función apply pasan algunas cosas que se tienen que mencionar,

- `df2[,unir]` esta filtrando las columnas del data.frame que se quieren unir.
- `MARGIN=1` le indica a apply que itere sobre las filas del data.frame anterior, si fuese igual a 2 se iteraría sobre las columnas.
- `function(x)` es la acción que queremos se realice sobre cada fila de data.frame.

Siempre puedes revisar la ayuda de `?apply` para conocer más.

**Usando tidyr**

Una ventaja que veo al usar tidyr es que podemos seleccionar las variables que queremos unir con el [tidy-select](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/dplyr_tidy_select.html), una herramienta muy útil que por ejemplo nos permite seleccionar un rango de variables continuas con el operador `:`.

```
library(tidyr)
#StringsAsFactor=F pues la funcion unite de tidyr
#no remueve los NA de factores
df <- data.frame(col1,col2, col3,stringsAsFactors=F)
df

df2<-df
# el uso de tidy-select ":" nos permite selecionar un rango 
# de variables, entonces si tienes 100 va. puedes hacer col1:col100
# siempre y cunado las variables sean consecutivas 
df2<-df2%>%unite("UNIDOS",col1:col3,sep="",remove=F,na.rm=T)
df2
  UNIDOS col1 col2   col3
1    Uno  Uno <NA>   <NA>
2    dos <NA>  dos   <NA>
3   tres tres <NA>   <NA>
4 cuatro <NA> <NA> cuatro
```